# Get the most recent row from the two duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like this:

| Change_Key | Serial_No | Part_Key | Quantity | Tare_Weight | Gross_Weight | Net_Weight | Update_Date | Last_Action | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8396682462 | 1Q2171213 | 6326442 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Mon Feb 05 2024 13:59:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) | Updated at Source Container TrueUp Form | 1 |
| 8396682467 | 1Q2171213 | 6326442 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Mon Feb 05 2024 13:59:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) | Retire at Source Container TrueUp Form | 0 |

Here, I am not getting the latest row with correct "Active" status, because the time-stamps are identical. I am facing this issue for multiple Serial Nos. Can anyone help me with this?

This is what I have tried till now:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    t1.Change_Key, t1.Serial_No, t1.Part_Key, t1.Quantity,
    t1.Tare_Weight, t1.Gross_Weight, t1.Net_Weight,
    t1.Update_Date, t1.Last_Action, t1.Active
FROM 
    Part_v_Container_Change2 AS T1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         Serial_No, 
         MAX(Update_Date) AS Update_Date, 
         MAX(Change_Key) AS Change_Key 
     FROM 
         Part_v_Container_Change2 
     GROUP BY Serial_No) AS T2 ON T1.Serial_No = T2.Serial_No 
                               AND T1.Update_Date = T2.Update_Date
WHERE
    t1.Serial_No = '1Q2171213'
ORDER BY 
    1
```

And I tried this:

```
SELECT
    Change_Key, Serial_No, Part_Key, Quantity,
    Tare_Weight, Gross_Weight, Net_Weight,
    Update_Date, Last_Action, Active
FROM
    (SELECT
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Serial_No ORDER BY Update_Date DESC) AS rn
     FROM
         Part_v_Container_Change2 cc1) x
WHERE
    rn = 1
    AND Serial_No = '1Q2171213' 
ORDER BY
    1
```

However, both the above is returning an incorrect result where `Active` is "1", which is the first entry.

| Change_Key | Serial_No | Part_Key | Quantity | Tare_Weight | Gross_Weight | Net_Weight | Update_Date | Last_Action | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8396682462 | 1Q2171213 | 6326442 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Mon Feb 05 2024 13:59:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) | Updated at Source Container TrueUp Form | 1 |

What I am expecting is the recent entry where `Active` is "0" with its appropriate `Change_Key`.

| Change_Key | Serial_No | Part_Key | Quantity | Tare_Weight | Gross_Weight | Net_Weight | Update_Date | Last_Action | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8396682467 | 1Q2171213 | 6326442 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Mon Feb 05 2024 13:59:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) | Retire at Source Container TrueUp Form | 0 |

Comment: your date values are identical, so you need a tie breaker, why not just order by `Active`?

Comment: @Stu, Because it is not fixed that I will always get last entry as Active = 0, for some entries the last entry s Active = 1, hence, cannot order by Active column

Comment: You need an auto-incrementing field in this table to fix issues like this. Is that what Change_key is?

Comment: why not `row_number() over(partition by Serial_No order by TimeStamp DESC, Active)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: @siggemannen, unfortunately no, because that's what I have tried, have posted the same in my question :(

Comment: No, you haven't, you can sort by two columns like i wrote

Comment: @siggemannen, Sorry Sir, I missed you earlier comment. I tried to run the query that you suggested but if I try by sorting two columns, like including Active in sorting then it will pick the entry based on the Active flag's number. If next time the latest entry has flag 1, it will still pick the entry having flag 0.

Comment: Add some more data so one can understand the problem. It should work for your sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds from your post that the column "Change_Key" could be used to identify the more recently inserted row, if my assumption is correct that it is a unique field that increments on each insert.

From your first attempt, it looks like you tried to use it in the subquery, but then you didn't join by it, which is why the other row is ultimately being selected.

Using your example and adding joining by Change_Key, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT top 1
t1.Change_Key,t1.Serial_No,t1.Part_Key,t1.Quantity,t1.Tare_Weight,t1.Gross_Weight,t1.Net_Weight,t1.Update_Date,t1.Last_Action,t1.Active
FROM Part_v_Container_Change2 AS T1
INNER JOIN
( SELECT Serial_No , MAX(Update_Date) AS Update_Date, max(Change_Key) as Change_Key FROM Part_v_Container_Change2 
GROUP BY Serial_No
) AS T2
ON T1.Serial_No = T2.Serial_No AND T1.Update_Date = T2.Update_Date AND T1.Change_Key = T2.Change_Key
where t1.Serial_No = '1Q2171213'
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: Formatting and layout could be a lot clearer

Answer (score -1):

If the timestamps are identical, you won't be able to get the latest one.  Change_Key looks like a better column to sort on.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment.